# Como omitir la validacion de Bootstrap en solo un input del formulario?

Tags: bootstrap, validación

Tengo un formulario y sus validaciones configuradas con boostrap  pero tengo una validación personalizada con javascript y quiero saber como puedo omitir la validacion de boostrap de ese input unicamente.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" class="needs-validation" method="post" action="<?= pubUrl ?>" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="Datos Adicionales" class="form-label">Datos Adicionales</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-people-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"></path>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.216 14A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216z"></path>
                <path d="M4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
      <input type="text" name="data" id="data" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="submit"></button>
</form>
```

como puedo

Comment: Quita `required` y has la prueba

Comment: no me sirve porque cuando agrego la clase .was-validate al form igual se marca de rojo y es lo que no quiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la unica forma que encontre para omitir de la validacion dejar de usar la clase .was-validate al formulario ya que al hacerlo de validan todos los input dentro.

Asi que recorri cada input por separado y gestione su validacion agregando las clases .is-valid y .is-invalid. y omitiendo claro el input que no queria validar con bootstrap.

```
function validateInput(input){
    if(input.classList.contains('is-invalid')){
        input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
      }
      input.classList.add('is-valid')
}
function invalidateInput(input){
  if(input.classList.contains('is-valid')){
        input.classList.remove('is-valid')
      }
      
      input.classList.add('is-invalid')
}

 let inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input, select');
        inputs.forEach((el)=>{
          if(el.checkValidity()){
            validateInput(el);
          }else{
            invalidateInput(el)
          }

          if(el.id != "data"){
            el.addEventListener('change',function(){
              if(el.checkValidity()){
                validateInput(el);
              }else{
                invalidateInput(el)
              }
            })
          }
        })
```